# Set up wraparound effect in libGDX with Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d

i have been having trouble trying  to set up wraparound in LibGDX using box2D, for example i want my player to appear at the left side of the screen after exiting the right side, but its not working here is my code:

```
public void setWraparound(){
    //if player goes out of bounds vertically
    if(body.getPosition().x < 0){
        body.setTransform(new Vector2(4.8f, body.getPosition().y),body.getAngle());
    }else if(body.getPosition().x > 4.8f){
        body.setTransform(new Vector2(0, body.getPosition().y), body.getAngle());
    }

    //if player goes out of bounds Horizontally
    if(body.getPosition().y < 0){
        body.setTransform(new Vector2(body.getPosition().x,8f), body.getAngle());
    }else if(body.getPosition().y > 8f){
        body.setTransform(new Vector2(body.getPosition().x,0), body.getAngle());
    }

}
```

Then i call the method in my GameStage class like this:

```
 public GameStage() {
    setUpWorld();
    setupCamera();
    setupTouchControls();
    player.setWraparound();
    renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
}
```

anyone to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where you call your `setWraparound` method is wrong. You need to call it after a collision of the player with screen border happens. I suggest you do the following

1. Create static bodies for each screen border (you could use for example EdgeShape for that)
2. Add a `ContactListener` to your box2D world and check in the `beginContact` method if player & wall do touch.
3. Now after touch was detected call your method `setWraparound`

Alternatively you could create a Sensor that matches the screen size and detect if player touches the sensor borders. Or you could just check every frame your player's x/y positions and see if they are out of the screen, but it is better to use box2D collision detection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but i have fixed it, the issue was that i did not call the    setWraparound method in the render method of libgdx needs to check that continuously.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean by "check every frame". However, since you use box2D I suggest you look into collision detection ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much i will use collision with EdgeShape as you said. by the way am kind of new to game develoment.